# HTML Table with Sticky Headers - Cell width issue

Tags: html, css

I am working with a html table that has sticky headers, in the css I am setting the cell width using

```
th, td { width:110px }
```

this works when the screen is at full width, however when the screen \ frame is smaller than 100% or the table is too big for the window the table header and detail rows go out of alignment.

this is the full css of the file

```
table tbody, table thead
{
display: block;
/*display: table-header-group;*/
table-layout: fixed;
}
table tbody  
{
overflow: auto;
height: 300px;
}
th, td { width:110px }
.colSelector tbody td:nth-child(1) {
width: 260px; 
}
.statusSelector tbody td:nth-child(1) {
width: 200px;
}
.statusSelector{ height: 150px;}
```

statusSelector and colSelector render fine as they are single table columsn that are generated by asp.net therefore never grow larger than the page or frame.

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this alignment issue as it seems that sticky headers are not easy to work with because of this issue.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/dkreLLec/) of the issue.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/? That would make debugging and stuff much easier.

Comment: @TempestasLudi i will make one in a few minutes

Comment: @TempestasLudi sorry it took me longer than i originally said, heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/dkreLLec/

Comment: Could you please define the problem more clearly in your post (use edit)? The only "problem" I see is that you are trying to display too much data at once, which results into a very large table, with colums that are too narrow to contain their information. That is not really a HTML/CSS problem, but more of a design issue.

Comment: @TempestasLudi that is the problem, in full screen it renders fine, but when i reduce the screen size or use the table in an iframe which is what the customer is wanting then it goes out of alignment.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's just because you have too much columns and too little space. You could, however, define a min-width for the table, if that is what you want. Then the table will have a minimum width, allowing for good alignment in narrow spaces, but if more space is available, it will expand. If that is what you mean, I'll re-post this as an answer ;) Considering any upvotes and stuff ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92061/discussion-between-simon-price-and-tempestas-ludi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could add:

```
table{
    width: 2200px;
}
```

or

```
table{
    min-width: 2200px;
}
```

;)
That is 20 columns with `110px` each. I'd prefer the first one.